# What does it look like to pass an address to a function, but it actually receives a pointer to a pointer at all?

Tags: c, pointers

today I started learning dynamic assignments and I wanted to ask you about the following piece of code I created,

```
void  getCharLen(char **pArray) {
    char *str = NULL;
    int len;
    char insStr[255];
    printf("Enter String");
    strcpy(insStr, "Exmaple");
    
    len = strlen(insStr) + 1;
    str = (char*)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    if (str != NULL)
        strcpy(str, insStr);
    *pArray = str;
}
```

The main:

```
int main(){
    char *CheckingString = NULL;
    getCharLen(&CheckingString );
}
```

My question is, how can we pass to a function that should receive a pointer to a pointer, simply an address of a pointer, and the compiler doesn't yell at us that we need to CASTING to a double pointer?
How does the memory look like we are passing the address of a pointer, but the function looks at it as a pointer to a pointer?

I tried to draw the references, and I just couldn't figure out how it happens.
I would really appreciate it if someone could explain with a drawing what is happening here

** AFTER EDIT**

What Im trying to ask, is why in the function Im calling to Char ** that is actually something like A but in the end of the call, we get An array like in B

[image: A VS B]

Comment: If you have a pointer variable and you acquire its address (not the address the variable holds; rather the address *of* the variable itself) using the `&` operator, what do you think the result is if it *isn't* a pointer-to-pointer? Related, *"we need to CASTING"* is far, far rarer than you think, and often is a sign you're doing something *wrong* rather than fixing anything.

Comment: Because `CheckingString` is a pointer to `char` (i.e. `char *`), then `&CheckingString` will be a pointer to a pointer to `char` (i.e. `char **`). I'm not sure I understand your problem or your question since the shown code does what it should.

Comment: Indeed the code works, but I wanted to know how the transfer of the pointers to the string really goes with the help of some kind of drawing, I mean how &CheckString looks like when the function suppose to get Pointer to pointer (Char **) but you only give an address of a Pointer, Maybe when you send An address of a pointer is it like so send pointer to pointer (char **)?

Comment: Take a step back... If `main()` declared `int x = 0`, there's no problem passing the address of `x`' to a func() that sets the value of that location... In your example, replace `x`, telling the compiler "this is a ptr to char"... The function doesn't receive `int *ptrX`... Your function receives an address to be used as a pointer whose value is a pointer to char. The biggest hurdle is to realise that `&int` and `&char*` are ALMOST the same... 'Almost' because the compiler ensures you use int*'s as int*'s and char*'s as char*'s... (especially for "pointer arithmetic" like incrementing...)

Comment: `&CheckString ` *is* the address of a `char*` pointer variable, and therefore a pointer-to-pointer *value*, in this case a `char**`. That's why it is correct for that call which expects a `char**` value, and thus why it works. If you thought it should be something else, or thought something *other* than a cast was needed (because it's not; we already discussed that), you should elaborate that point of confusion in your question further.

Comment: What is the difference between an _address_ and a _pointer_, for you? Please add this to your question by [edit]ing it, this seems to be the source of your confusion.

Comment: I think you are right,
I think a pointer is a pointer to an address and inside the address there is some value
That is, for example pX---> 0x000004--->10
Pointer to the address in memory where the value is located

Comment: I edited my question, I would appreciate it if you could take a look please

Answer (score 1):

`char *pc` denotes a pointer to a character. You can pass it as the address of some character variable, or as a character array (implicitly turned to the address of the first element);

```
void Call(char *pc) {}

char c;
Call(&c);

char s[5];
Call(s);
```

`char **pc` denotes a pointer to a pointer to a character. You can pass it as the address of some variable that contains the address of a character (or of an array of characters) or as an array of pointers to characters (or arrays of characters).

```
void Call(char **pc) {}

char c;
char* pc= &c;
Call(&pc);

char s[5];
pc= s;
Call(&pc);

char* ps[5];
ps[0]= &c; ps[1]= ...
Call(ps);

ps[0]= s; ps[1]= ...
Call(ps);
```

Comment: I edited my question, I would appreciate it if you could take a look please

Comment: @Bubi: I have no idea what this means.

Comment: I tried to draw from the right my point of view of how Char ** looks compared to Char*,
And I tried to relate it to what our function is supposed to receive, CHAR ** and in practice it only receives CHAR *

Comment: @Bubi: "is supposed to receive, CHAR ** and in practice it only receives CHAR *": please explain.

Comment: I meant, as you can see, in the getCharLen(char **pArray) function, we are supposed to give our function a pointer to an array of pointers, in practice, we just pass the address of a pointer.
According to what was said above when we do &pX it actually functions as a pointer of a pointer, but in the end, what this function returns to me is an array of letters (as in drawing B) and I ask why it is not like in drawing A

Comment: @Bubi: C-style arrays are immaterial. They are only "represented" by a pointer to the first element, and their length is even unknown. So ponder that you *can't* pass or return an array.

Answer (score 0):

If we "draw" it, it's like this (before the call)

```
+-----------------+      +----------------+
| &CheckingString | ---> | CheckingString | ---> NULL
+-----------------+      +----------------+
```

That is, `&CheckingString` is a pointer to `CheckingString`. And `CheckingString` is a pointer that has been initialized to point to `NULL`.

After the call it's almost the same:

```
+-----------------+      +----------------+      +-----------+
| &CheckingString | ---> | CheckingString | ---> | "Exmaple" |
+-----------------+      +----------------+      +-----------+
```

It might help if you start calling the `&` operator the *pointer-to* operator, because that's what it does: It give you a *pointer to* a variable. So a *pointer to* a pointer variable is a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: As always, thank you very much for your help! So if I understood correctly according to what you write, a pointer's address is actually a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: @Bubi Yes that's correct.

Comment: So actually after the dynamic assignment, what is inside CheckString is actually a pointer to an array of pointers?
Or we have a pointer to an array that contains the "example"

Comment: @Bubi CheckString is a pointer to an array of characters ("ptr to a null terminated string" after its value is assigned.) Your function receives the address of CheckString, calling that ptr-to-ptr value "pArray"... "pArray" is misleading because it points to an array containing only one element...

Comment: I edited my question, I would appreciate it if you could take a look please